# How do I embed a Silverlight control into a Facelets page?

Tags: silverlight, jsf-2, facelets

I am trying to embed a Silverlight control into a JSF 2.0 page, which is using Facelets, however, I am receiving a very ambiguous error message when the page renders.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?  I have my clientaccesspolicy.xml, and silverlight.js in place.

When I remove the `<object>` tag, the JSF page displays correctly
If I place the `<object>` tag into a vanilla HTML page, the silverlight control renders correctly in my Tomcat 7.0.25.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:cayman="http://www.fnet.com/cayman/jsf"
template="/WEB-INF/jsf/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="title">Home Page</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">

    <h:form>
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="loginBean" value="#{UserLoginComponent}" />
        </ui:include>
        <div>
            <p:growl />
        </div>
        <center>
            <p:panel header="Home Page">
                <f:verbatim escape="#{true}">
                    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,"
                        type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <param name="source" value="Dashboard.xap" />
                        <a
                            href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0"
                            style="text-decoration: none"> <img
                                src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376"
                                alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none" />
                        </a>
                    </object>
                </f:verbatim>
                <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame"
                    style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: 0px"></iframe>
                <h:inputHidden id="userid" value="ADMINISTRATOR" />
                <h:inputHidden id="password" value="admin" />
                <h:inputHidden id="adminserviceuurl"
                    value="http://129.196.218.35:8080/cayman/services" />


            </p:panel>
        </center>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<f:verbatim>`. It's a leftover from the old ages of JSF 1.x on JSP and deprecated in JSF 2.x.

As to the ambiguous error message which you forgot to include in your question, make sure that you're properly escaping [XML special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) like `&`. Facelets is a XML based view technology and will be parsed by a XML parser before generating the HTML. The XML parser will choke when it encounters `&` which is supposed to represent the start of an entity, but there is no `;` to denote the end of an entity or when the entity by itself does not represent anything at all.

So, replace

```
href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0"
```

by

```
href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&amp;v=4.0.50826.0"
```

Comment: Thanks, for this and many other posting that you have answered.  (Never had a chance to thank you since they weren't mine.)  

I went down all sorts of rabbit holes, without realizing that the problem was not the verbatim tags, but the silverlight javascript functions.  When I stripped everything out of the page except the verbatim and the object tags, then it worked.  And, as you noted the verbatim tags were not needed, so I have since removed them.

Comment: And, btw...  Originally I had a stacktrace, but now that I look at my original posting, it is gone.  Strange, it was there when I posted.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd bet it to be just a XML parsing error. That can also happen when you include some JS code in a XML file. JS has operators like `&`, `<`, etc which needs to be escaped when embedded in XML. Best is to just put JS code in its own JS file which you include by `<h:outputScript>`.